# How to apply operations after uniform_ form torch in Python?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, fast-ai

I have

```
x = torch.ones(n,3) 
x[:,0].uniform_(-1.,1)
x[:5]
```

And I got

```
tensor([[-0.4899,  1.0000,  1.0000],
        [ 0.7395,  1.0000,  1.0000],
        [-0.3599,  1.0000,  1.0000],
        [ 0.0863,  1.0000,  1.0000],
        [ 0.8935,  1.0000,  1.0000]])
```

What I want to achieve is to assign random value to first and second row 
and to make the first row squared

`[0.25,0.5,1]` (an example)

I have few questions:

- how to apply the same `uniform_` to only two rows?
- Is there a square function, and how to apply it to only first row?
- Can it be done in one operation?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it like this

```
x = torch.ones(n,3) 
x[:,1].uniform_(-1.,1.)
x[:,0] = x[:,1]**2
x[:5]
```

With output

```
tensor([[ 0.8429, -0.9181,  1.0000],
        [ 0.0638,  0.2525,  1.0000],
        [ 0.5168,  0.7189,  1.0000],
        [ 0.7832,  0.8850,  1.0000],
        [ 0.2592,  0.5091,  1.0000]])
```

I would still gladly accept better answer :)